# Using an element from a table in selecting columns/rows in R

Tags: r

I've been working on a process to create all possible combinations of unique integers for lengths `1:n`. I found the `nCr` function (combn function in the combinat package to be useful here).

Once all unique occurrences are iterated, they are appended to a consolidation table that contains any possible length+combination of the digits `1:n`. A subset of the final table's relevant column (one record) looks like this (column is named String and the subset table `f1`):

```
c(1,3,4,5,9,10)
```

I need to select these columns from a secondary data source (`df`) one at a time (I am going to loop through this table), so my logic was to use this code:

```
df[,f1$String]
```

However, I get a message that says that undefined columns are selected, but if I copy and paste the contents of the cell such as:

```
df[,c(1, 3, 4, 5, 9, 10)]
```

it works fine ... I've tried all I can think of at this point; if anyone has some insight it would be greatly appreciated.

Code to reproduce is:

```
library(combinat)
library(data.table)
library(plyr)
rm(list=ls())

NCols=10 
NRows=10 
myMat<-matrix(runif(NCols*NRows), ncol=NCols) 
XVars <- as.data.frame(myMat)
colnames(XVars) <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j")
x1 <- as.data.frame(colnames(XVars[1:ncol(XVars)]))
colnames(x1) <- "Independent.Variable"
setDT(x1)[, Index := .GRP, by = "Independent.Variable"]

colClasses = c("character", "numeric", "numeric")
col.names = c("String", "r!", "n!")
Combination <- read.table(text = "", colClasses = colClasses, col.names = col.names)

for(i in 1:nrow(x1)){
  x2<- as.data.frame(combn(nrow(x1),i))
  for (i in 1:ncol(x2)){
    x3 <- paste("c(",paste(x2[1:nrow(x2),i], collapse = ", "), ")", sep="")
    x3 <- as.data.frame(x3)
    colnames(x3) <- "String"
    x3 <- mutate(x3, "r!" = nrow(x2))
    x3 <- mutate(x3, "n!" = nrow(x1))
    Combination <- rbind(Combination, x3)
  }
}

setDT(Combination)[, Index := .GRP, by = c("String", "r!", "n!")]
f1 <- Combination[717,]
f1$String <- as.character(f1$String)

## reference to data frame
myMat[,(f1$String)]
## pasted element
myMat[, c(1, 3, 4, 5, 9, 10)]
```

Comment: Could you provide an output of `f1$String`?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: The output of f1$String is: c(1, 3, 4, 5, 9, 10)

Comment: @Anton89 something is not clear with your table `f1`. Is `f1$String` a factor?

Comment: @NathanWerth Nathan, please see reproducible code edited into the original question

Comment: @ANG yes, it's stored as a factor

Answer (score 0):

`f1$String` is the string `"c(1, 3, 4, 5, 9, 10)"`. When you use `myMat[,(f1$String)]`, R will look for the column with name "c(1, 3, 4, 5, 9, 10)". To get column numbers 1,3,4,5,9,10, you have to parse the string to an R expression and evaluate it first:

`myMat[,eval(parse(text=f1$String))]`

Comment: It works fine. One should be careful when using `eval()` here. Try this and see the result `x <- c("1", "3", "4", "5", "9", "10")`
`eval(parse(text=x))`

Comment: In that case you can just use `sapply(x,function(y)eval(parse(text=y)))`.

Answer (score 0):

As @user3794498 noticed, you set `f1$String` `as.character()` so you cannot use is to get the columns you want. 
You can change the way you define `f1` or extract the column numbers from `f1$String`. Something like this should also work (load `stringr` before) `myMat[, f1$String %>% str_match_all("[0-9]+") %>% unlist %>% as.numeric]`.